# Recommendations for C++ open source game engines on IPhone

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, sio2, oolong

I decided that I want to make a game for the iphone I was thinking of using oolong or sio2 any recommendations?

Both have the problem of lack of tutorials, is it possible to somehow use a normal C++ game tutorial and  integreate the engines rather than the one used in the tutorials? So if the C++ tutorial talks of creating an engine I can skip it and use sio2 or oolong?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiousity, what type of game were you thinking of?  Please don't say RPG though.

Comment: I would like to start with some sort of basic first person shooter, never been a big fan of RPGs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a game, not a game engine.  The short answer is, yes, you can just use those engines to make the game.

The long answer is that you should probably go through the tutorials doing it the way that they do it just to get a feeling for C++/OpenGL/whatever.  Then, using the knowledge that you have gained, make your own game using oolong or SIO.  Trust me, you are not going to want to use the code you wrote when you were learning C++ to make an actual game, unless you can read something and immediately master it.

Comment: Thats great advice thanks :)  The bit I dont understand is once I've gone over say a c++ tutorial for an FPS and then decide I want to redo it with sio2, how will I know which parts are going to become si02 code and which stay the same? Sio2 can use C++ code so will it mostly stay the same?

Comment: That's why many people (myself included) call this an art ;-).  In general though, you should do *everything* that sio2 supports doing with its systems.  They are well-tested, while yours are not.

Comment: That make sense, but wouldnt this mean I would have to look up each line in the tutorials with the sio2 documentation to see if there is an sio2 command for that particular line of code?

Comment: Probably not, since it's all C++, right?  You will probably find yourself doing translation for more *huge chunks* than line-by-line.  And you'll probably find you initial design to be bad in the first place so you'll just want to re-write the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying just one last thing. So even once i've 'translated' the required parts of c++ to sio2 from tutorials I'll probably have to re-write the code again from begining to improve it?

Comment: soi2 is a framework, so you'll still be programming in C++...but yes, you'll have to re-write code and improve it (unless you wrote it perfectly the first time).

Answer (score 0):

Look into Unity.  Not C++ for the scripting, but it's a very popular engine.

Answer (score 0):

How about [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/)? It's BSD license, has docs and tutorials, and I've seen many people use it to create a game in a day.

Comment: I've heard cocos2d is really good too, the only problem is that its 2d and I really want to focus on 3d.